# How do I find new missions in GTA San Andreas?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

I have completed all of Ryder's missions, and completed up to the "Drive-By" mission from Sweet. Now I can't find any more mission to enter. How can I find new missions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the missions list found on:
**SPOILERS AHEAD WARNING!**
http://www.gta-sanandreas.com/guides/missions/lossantos.php your next mission set would be:

- **Sweets Girl**

But the link i provided should help you.
Otherwice, missions are found on the map marked with a letter.

Comment: I continued with Bigs missions. But could not find anymore Sweet's mission. Can they be available later in the game?

Comment: I wouldn't ruin the game for you by spoiling you with info :)

Answer (score 1):

There are certain times when you need to acquire more territories to continue with the game

Answer (score 0):

You mention on Atlas EU's answer that you haven't completed missions for Big Smoke yet. You usually need to have completed some, if not all missions for all *currently active* people before getting new missions.

Of the people/groups in Los Santos, here's the ones that will offer you missions (that I can remember off the top of my head):

- Sweet (Your brother)
- Ryder (Gang member/childhood friend)
- Big Smoke (Gang member/childhood friend)
- C.R.A.S.H ('Any means necessary' Cops)
- OG Loc (Gangsta friend)
- Caesar (Sister's boyfriend, Racing enthusiast)